# jQuery Mobile: add text to ID after changepage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

After a user logs in I set their username in HTML5 localstorage. I want to set the username into the top toolbar on the next page, but for some reason it wont change the text after `changepage`. The page changes but the text is not inserted. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
 success: function(data) { 
        if(data.status == "success") {
                $.mobile.changePage("inventory.html");
                var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
                $("#top_username").html(username);  
            };
        if(data.status == "failed") {
            alert('Incorrect Login Information');
            };
        }
```

EDIT:

Comment: Why not simply: `$("#top_username").html(username);` cause your local getItem is already stored in var `username`

Comment: @roXon that was a mistake when I transferred over the code

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){ // DOM is ready! wow, go for #top_username

    var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    $("#top_username").html(username);

});
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue. The code wasn't complete, it is part of an AJAX call - Please see revised code.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are trying to add your html content from previous page 
the

```
var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
$("#top_username").html(username);
```

Should be in inventory.html page and there you should have inside a function something like this

```
$(document).on('pageinit').
```

Then it should work perfectly.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing page all activities intended for new page must be done during the new page events execution.

In your case you have to options:

1. Let's say your new page id is newpage us this event to change it:

   ```
   $('#newpage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){
       var username = localStorage.getItem('username');
       $("#top_username").html('<h1>' + username + '</h1>');
   }
   ```
2. ```
   $('#newpage').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){
       // Get it from prevPage
       var username = data.prevPage.find('#username').val();
       $("#top_username").html('<h1>' + username + '</h1>');
   }
   ```